# Symfony2 and avoiding overly verbose code

Tags: php, symfony, loose-coupling

In most of my controllers, I need to get a reference to one or more of my custom entity repositories, so naturally, I do this a lot:

```
/** @var $repo MyFirstEntityRepository */
$repo1 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MyNamespaceMyBundle:MyFirstEntity');
/** @var $repo MySecondEntityRepository */
$repo2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MyNamespaceMyBundle:MySecondEntity');
/** @var $repo MyThirdEntityRepository */
$repo3 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MyNamespaceMyBundle:MyThirdEntity');
```

My question is: if I have a bunch of different Entities that I need a repository reference for, is it good practice to create a bunch of corresponding `get[EntityName]Repository` methods in some sort of `BaseController` which all other controllers could inherit from?

The refactored controller code would be more like:

```
$repo1 = $this->getMyFirstEntityRepository();
$repo2 = $this->getMySecondEntityRepository();
$repo3 = $this->getMyThirdEntityRepository();
```

Which would play nicely with IDE autocompletion and type inference as well.

Is this good practice? Or does it violate some sort of standard? Does it make the code any less "loosely coupled"?

Comment: Which part might not be possible? All my controllers already inherit from a common `BaseController` that I created (which extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`)

Comment: Just for given you a hint - if you would use PHPStorm with the Symfony2 Plugin you could save lots of annotations for typehinting. Here you will find a teaser of the plugin: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
/** @var $repo MyFirstEntityRepository */
$repo1 = $em->getRepository('MyNamespaceMyBundle:MyFirstEntity');
/** @var $repo MySecondEntityRepository */
$repo2 = $em->getRepository('MyNamespaceMyBundle:MySecondEntity');
/** @var $repo MyThirdEntityRepository */
$repo3 = $em->getRepository('MyNamespaceMyBundle:MyThirdEntity');
```

Seems to me declaring variable `$em` solves all the DRY violations...

Comment: Simple yet effective. I guess the only drawback is lack of (automatic) IDE code completion etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the [Model Manager](http://problematic.io/2012/03/12/putting-your-symfony2-controllers-on-a-diet-part-2/) approach.  You could then, in turn, use the [JMSDiExtraBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle) to make instantiation even easier.

Note: If you're using Symfony 2.2, then you probably already have the JMSDiExtraBundle installed, since it was part of the standard distribution in that version.